# Count down from user entered number in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have an input box that a user can enter a number into and upon clicking Commit, that number displays in a

tag.

I then want this number to start counting down when I click Start.

I am new to Javascript and this is essentially a little project to help me learn, maybe I've thrown myself in too far, but I'm too invested now and would appreciate any help.

My HTML:

```
<span style="font-size: 36pt; font-family: homiziothin; color: black; padding-right: 20px;">&pound;</span>
<input id="inputvalue" type="number" name="Value" min="0" max="500">
<button id="commitprice" type="submit" onclick="submitPrice()">Commit Price</button>
<p id="submittedprice"></p>
<button id="startauction" type="submit" onclick="startAuction()">Start Auction</button>
```

and my current Javascript to get the user value into the

tag (and a rough guess going from multiple searches on google of how to start the countdown)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitPrice()
    {
        var $pricesubmitted = $("#inputvalue").val();

        $("#submittedprice").text($pricesubmitted);
    }
    function startAuction()
    {
        debugger;
        var $startingprice = $("#inputvalue").val();

        var $bidcountdown = setInterval(function()
        {
            $startingprice--;
            document.getElementById("#inputvalue").textContent = $startingprice;
            if($startingprice <= 0)
                clearInterval($bidcountdown);
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

At the moment it's erroring and saying that textContent can't be NULL.

***Also just to point out the Actual populating of the P tag is working, its the countdown that isn't.***

Comment: For `input` you want to use `.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented your requirement in a fiddle, you can check

```js
  function submitPrice() {
    var $pricesubmitted = document.getElementById("inputvalue");
    document.getElementById("submittedprice").innerText = $pricesubmitted.value;
  }

function startAuction() {
  var msgElement = document.getElementById("showMessage");
  msgElement.innerText = "Count Down Started..";
  var _el = document.getElementById("inputvalue");
  var $startingprice = parseInt(_el.value);
  var $bidcountdown = setInterval(function() {
    msgElement.innerText = "Count Value " + $startingprice;
    $startingprice--;
    msgElement.innerText = $startingprice;
    if ($startingprice < 0) {
      msgElement.innerText = "Count Down ends ...";
      clearInterval($bidcountdown);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size: 36pt; font-family: homiziothin; color: black; padding-right: 20px;">&pound;</span>

<input id="inputvalue" type="number" name="Value" min="0" max="500" value="">

<button id="commitprice" onclick="submitPrice()">Commit Price</button>

<p id="submittedprice"></p>

<button id="startauction" type="button" onclick="startAuction()">Start Auction</button>

<div id="showMessage"></div>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/q28b9ajz/)

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you for taking the time to do this, i'll take a look, break it down and make sure i understand how you did it :)

Answer (score 3):

[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property represents the text between opening and closing tags of an element. With your `input`, you need `value` property, because you don't have any text between those tags.

More info: [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: Also since you are using jquery already just rewrite `document.getElementById("#inputvalue").textContent = $startingprice;` into `$("#inputvalue").val($startingprice);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also the comment on the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues in your code.  First, as noted by Mladen, you should be using .value instead of .textContent.  Second, you should not use the "#" in the .getElementById selector.

This should fix it for you.

```
function startAuction()
{
    debugger;
    var $startingprice = document.getElementById("inputvalue").value;

    var $bidcountdown = setInterval(function()
    {
        $startingprice--;
        // document.getElementById("inputvalue").value = $startingprice;
        document.getElementById("submittedprice").innerHTML= $startingprice;
        if($startingprice <= 0)
            clearInterval($bidcountdown);
    }, 1000);
}
```

By the way, I highly recommend not jumping back and forth between jQuery and vanilla JS DOM selectors to avoid this kind of confusion.

**Edit:**

Commented out the line targeting the text input and added a line targeting the `<p>` tag.  Note that instead of `.value`, you will need to use `.innerHTML` to make the change to the `<p>` tag (because it is updating the HTML contained within the opening and classing brackets of the `<p>`).

Comment: So this is working thank you, i have just noticed though that the number in the input box is counting down and not the number that is now in the P tag. A pastebin here so you can see what i trying to achieve here: https://pastebin.com/21ctir2n